# how to display N number of images using matplotlib?

Tags: python, image, matplotlib

I want to display some images using matplotlib, don't know how it is achieved.

Any suggestions are welcome!

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[Matplotlib documentation](http://matplotlib.org/examples/pylab_examples/multi_image.html) has a nice example.  You could copy and paste most of the code to apply it to your images.